# cannot save tensorflow recommender model: input shape is not available or because the forward pass of the model is not defined

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I have the following training code:

```py
from typing import Dict, Text

import os 
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

import pandas as pd
import tensorflow_recommenders as tfrs

base_path = "/Users/pthieu/Downloads/Commit/platform"

users_path = base_path + "/tt-users.csv"
jobs_path = base_path + "/tt-jobs.csv"
pos_path = base_path + "/tt-actions-positive.csv"
neg_path = base_path + "/tt-actions-negative.csv"


class RetrievalModel(tfrs.Model):
  def __init__(self, user_model, job_model, task):
    super().__init__()
    self.job_model: tf.keras.Model = job_model
    self.user_model: tf.keras.Model = user_model
    self.task: tf.keras.layers.Layer = task

  def call(self, features):
    # We pick out the user features and pass them into the user model.
    user_embeddings = self.user_model(features["user_id"])
    # And pick out the features and pass them into the job model,
    # getting embeddings back.
    positive_embeddings = self.job_model(features['job_id'])
    return user_embeddings, positive_embeddings

  def compute_loss(self, features: Dict[Text, tf.Tensor], training=False) -> tf.Tensor:
    # We pick out the user features and pass them into the user model.
    user_embeddings = self.user_model(features["user_id"])
    # And pick out the features and pass them into the job model,
    # getting embeddings back.
    positive_embeddings = self.job_model(features["job_id"])

    # The task computes the loss and the metrics.
    return self.task(user_embeddings, positive_embeddings)


def main():
  
  users_df = pd.read_csv(users_path)
  jobs_df = pd.read_csv(jobs_path)
  pos_df = pd.read_csv(pos_path)
  neg_df = pd.read_csv(neg_path)

  pos_df_dict = pos_df.to_dict(orient='list')
  pos_actions = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(pos_df_dict)

  # for x in pos_actions.take(1).as_numpy_iterator():
  #   pprint.pprint(x)

  pos_actions = pos_actions.map(lambda x: {
      "user_id": x["user_id"],
      "job_id": x["public_job_id"]
  })

  neg_df_dict = neg_df.to_dict(orient='list')
  neg_actions = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(neg_df_dict)

  neg_actions = neg_actions.map(lambda x: {
      "user_id": x["user_id"],
      "job_id": x["public_job_id"]
  })

  # ratings = pos_actions.concatenate(neg_actions)
  ratings = pos_actions

  # for _ in range(5):
  #     data = next(iter(ratings))
  #     print(data)


  jobs_df_dict = jobs_df.to_dict(orient='list')
  jobs = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(jobs_df_dict)

  users_df_dict = users_df.to_dict(orient='list')
  users = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(users_df_dict)

  # for _ in range(5):
  #     data = next(iter(jobs))
  #     print(data)

  ratings_len = ratings.cardinality().numpy()
  train_len = int(ratings_len*0.8)
  test_len = ratings_len - train_len

  seed = 42
  tf.random.set_seed(seed)
  shuffled = ratings.shuffle(ratings_len, seed=seed, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)

  train = shuffled.take(train_len)
  test = shuffled.skip(train_len).take(test_len)

  print(train)

  job_ids = jobs.batch(1_000).map(lambda x: x["id"])
  user_ids = users.batch(1_000).map(lambda x: x["id"])

  unique_job_ids = np.unique(np.concatenate(list(job_ids)))
  unique_user_ids = np.unique(np.concatenate(list(user_ids)))

  # unique_job_ids[:10]

  embedding_dimension = 32

  user_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(
        vocabulary=unique_user_ids, mask_token=None),
    # We add an additional embedding to account for unknown tokens.
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(unique_user_ids) + 1, embedding_dimension)
  ])

  job_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(
        vocabulary=unique_job_ids, mask_token=None),
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(unique_job_ids) + 1, embedding_dimension)
  ])

  # Metrics
  metrics = tfrs.metrics.FactorizedTopK(
    candidates=job_ids.map(job_model)
  )

  # Loss
  task = tfrs.tasks.Retrieval(
    metrics=metrics
  )

  model = RetrievalModel(user_model, job_model, task)
  model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adagrad(learning_rate=0.1))

  cached_train = train.shuffle(ratings_len).batch(256).cache()
  cached_test = test.batch(128).cache()
  #cached_train = train.shuffle(ratings_len).cache()
  #cached_test = test.cache()
  print(train)
  print(test)
  print(cached_train)
  print(cached_test)

  model.fit(cached_train, epochs=3)
  model.evaluate(cached_test, return_dict=True)

  filepath = os.path.join('.', 'retrieval_model')
  model.save(filepath)
  # tf.saved_model.save(model, filepath)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

When I save with `model.save`, I get the error:

```
ValueError: Model <__main__.RetrievalModel object at 0x147ee9710> cannot be saved either because the input shape is not available or because the forward pass of the model is not defined.To define a forward pass, please override `Model.call()`. To specify an input shape, either call `build(input_shape)` directly, or call the model on actual data using `Model()`, `Model.fit()`, or `Model.predict()`. If you have a custom training step, please make sure to invoke the forward pass in train step through `Model.__call__`, i.e. `model(inputs)`, as opposed to `model.call()`.
```